# Simulation of bullet with cannon

Tags: manipulate

I want to reproduce a  simulation involving a movable cannon and
a movable target of varying size. The cannon is fixed such that the vertical height is variable but the x and y position is fixed.

This is the code:

```
displacement[orign_List, velocity_, alpha_, gamma_, tEnd_] := 
With[{g = 9.8}, 
Select[If[tEnd <= 0, {}, 
Chop[Table[{origin[[1]] + velocity*t*Cos[alpha Pi/2], 
   origin[[2]] + velocity*t*Cos[gamma Pi], 
   origin[[3]] + velocity*t*Sin[alpha Pi/2] - 0.5 g*t^2, t}, {t, 
   0, tEnd, 0.25}]]], #[[3]] >= 0 &]]

velocity[velocity_, alpha_, gamma_, t_] := 
With[{g = 9.8}, 
Chop[If[t > 0, {velocity*Cos[alpha Pi/2], velocity*Cos[gamma Pi], 
 velocity*Sin[alpha Pi/2] - g t}, {0., 0., 0.}]]]

intersect[point_List, corner1_List, corner2_List] := 
point[[1]] >= corner1[[1]] && point[[1]] <= corner2[[1]] && 
point[[2]] >= corner1[[2]] && point[[2]] <= corner2[[2]] && 
point[[3]] >= corner1[[3]] && point[[3]] <= corner2[[3]]
intersection[points_List, corner1_List, corner2_List] := 
Or @@ (intersect[#, corner1, corner2] & /@ points)

With[{width = 200, height = 200, length = 200, limit = 10}, Manipulate[
DynamicModule[{b, Lx, Ly, Lz, cannonAlpha, cannonGamma, targetX, 
targetY, path, text, color, Vx, Vy, 
 Vz}, {cannonGamma, cannonAlpha} = cannonOrient;
{targetX, targetY} = targetPos;
b = cannonL Cos[(1 - cannonAlpha) Pi/2];
Lx = cannonL Cos[cannonAlpha Pi/2];
Ly = length/2 + cannonL Cos[cannonGamma Pi];
Lz = cannonL Sin[cannonAlpha Pi/2];
path = 
displacement[{Lx, Ly, cannonZb + Lz}, cannonVM, cannonAlpha, 
 cannonGamma, time];
tLast = If[Length[path] > 1, Last[path][[4]], 0];
{Vx, Vy, Vz} = velocity[cannonVM, cannonAlpha, cannonGamma, tLast];
color = 
If[intersection[
  path, {targetX, targetY, targetZ}, {targetX + targetL, 
   targetY + targetW, targetZ + targetH}], Red, Green];
Column[{
 Grid[{{"Vx", "Vy", "Vz"}, {Vx, Vy, Vz}}], 
 Graphics3D[{{Thickness[0.02], 
    Line[{{0, length/ 2, cannonZb}, {Lx, Ly, 
       Lz + cannonZb}}]}, {color, 
    Cuboid[{targetX, targetY, targetZ}, {targetX + targetL, 
      targetY + targetW, targetZ + targetH}]}, 
   Point[Most[#]] & /@ path}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, width}, {0, length}, {0, height}}, 
  ImageSize -> 300]}]],
 {{cannonVM, 50}, 10, 
 100}, {{cannonOrient, {0.5, 0.5}}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {cannonL, 20, 
 length/ 2}, {cannonZb, 0, 
 height/ 2}, {{targetPos, {100, 100}}, {5 limit, 0}, {width - limit,
 length - limit}}, {targetZ, 0, height - limit}, {targetL, limit, 
 length/2}, {targetW, limit, width/2}, {targetH, limit, 
 height/ 2}, {time, 0, 25}, {time, 0, 25, ControlType -> Trigger}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

But I don't understand why the path of the bullet isn't shown in the animation.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in the definition of displacement "orign"->"origin"